# Why does Visual Studio Code insert spaces when editing a Makefile and "editor.insertSpaces": "auto"?

Tags: makefile, visual-studio-code

make doesn't like spaces for the body of a target in a Makefile. Has to be a tab.

I changed "editor.insertSpaces" to "auto", thinking this would help. It didn't.

I had to set it to false in order to get the code working.

Comment: Presumably because Visual Studio didn't guess the type of file correctly. Does using `Makefile.mk` work correctly? Does it work if you edit an existing Makefile instead of starting a new one? Do you know (or is there documentation) on how Visual Studio guesses file type?

Comment: I've tried both an existing file and a new file, and in both cases 'auto' doesn't do the right thing. I did not try the .mk extension ... but VSC does guess the type of file correctly (looking at Language Mode in the lower right part of the screen)

Comment: So it recognizes `Makefile` as a makefile but `auto` still doesn't do the right thing? Then perhaps it doesn't know to do that for makefiles for some reason. I don't know. Sorry.

Answer (score 34):

This is now possible with Language Specific Settings.
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_language-specific-editor-settings

> To customize your editor by language, run the global command Preferences: Configure Language Specific Settings (command id: workbench.action.configureLanguageBasedSettings) from the Command Palette (<kbd>⇧⌘P</kbd>) which opens the language picker. Selecting the language you want, opens the Settings editor with the language entry where you can add applicable settings.

Once you have the editor open, enter the following configuration for `[makefile]`

```js
{
    "[makefile]": {
        "editor.insertSpaces": false,
        "editor.detectIndentation": false
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems that just use "editor.insertSpaces": false" can resolve that problem.

Comment: FYI, Command Palette is accessible from the View menu.

Answer (score 4):

VS Code does accurately guess the file type for a `Makefile`, but the language configuration does not specify tab style. There is an outstanding [pull request](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/pull/6542) that addresses this issue.

Before that PR lands, you may be able to fix this locally by editing the application itself. On OSX where applications are really just folders, you can find the language configuration for `Makefile`s in `Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/make`. Open up `make.configuration.json` and add `"insertSpaces": false` on line 2. That fixed it for me.

Comment: `make.configuration.json` is no longer existed, how to resolve it today?

Comment: @PaleNeutron If you haven't found something already, I posted an answer below that works with VS Code's language specific settings which now exist.

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio Code users that wish to use spaces as their indent character in the global configuration will have trouble editing Makefiles because it requires the user to use tabs as their indent character instead of spaces. Updating the configuration just to edit a few lines is not a viable solution IMO.

You can use the Command Palette (`View > Command Palette`) and type `Convert Indentation to Tabs` and hit `Enter`. You editor should now have updated all indentation to their corresponding tabs equivalent.