# VSCode insert tab character manually

Tags: tabs, visual-studio-code

When using VSCode, most of my files are set to be indented using spaces. However I sometimes wish to insert a literal tab. When I was using vim I'd use <Ctrl>+v <Tab> but that doesn't work with VSCode.

I've been searching and searching and cannot find anything. Please help!

Comment: if by chance it's for editing a `Makefile` then see https://stackoverflow.com/a/56060185/191246

Answer (score 71, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a generic solution, but you can setup a [keybinding](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings) for this:

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+v tab",
    "command": "type",
    "args": { "text": "\t" },
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
}
```

This keybinding will insert an tab character even when the current mode is spaces.

Comment: It's incredible how hard it is to find how to do this simple thing.

Comment: I suggest to use the shortcut `"key": "ctrl+k tab"` that is the default "prefix" for combined keys shortcut.

Comment: `ctrl+v tab` is inline with VI/VIM.  `ctrl+q tab` is inline with Emacs keybindings. That there is a suggested standard for VSCode keybindings is good to know too!

Comment: In case anyone else is looking:   Add this to the `keybindings.json` file, which is accessible via the Command Palette (⇧⌘P) Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)

Comment: `ctrl+q tab` works in vim, so might consider using that key chord in vscode keybindings so as to keep the default vscode behavior for `ctrl+v`

Comment: note this breaks the paste behavior since ctrl+v doesn't work anymore

Answer (score 95):

*Quick-and-dirty solution*: Find a tab somewhere else, then copy-paste.

Chances are that you already have a tab character in the file you are editing, but if not you can generate one in another application or text editor.

You can also generate a tab programmatically in a bash shell with the following command (the brackets are optional):

```
echo -e [\\t]
```

For your more immediate needs, I have inserted a tab character below...

```
    There is a tab character between these brackets: [	]
```

---

Another approach is to change the tab mode temporarily, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36884368/86967).

Comment: This doesn't work to me: pasted code gets auto-formatted and the tabs converted to a space. (VSCode 1.26.0)

Comment: @lapo, It sounds like you're trying to insert a tab character at a location where it is not allowed by your formatting rules.

Comment: Yes @nobar unfortunately VSCode has no way of supporting "mixed tabs/spaces" (as defined by Java and GNU standard indentation) and I was looking for a way to achieve that manually. (so far, I'm using 8-spaces and then find/replace… a bit messy)

Comment: perfect! i can't believe that this is actually the easiest way to do it, but i guess it just is. how could they forget about makefiles?

Comment: `echo -e "[\\t]"` Worker for me (MacOS)

Comment: This works for me, I have to  "intentionally" introduce a tab in a file.

Answer (score 39):

`<Alt> <Numpad: 0 0 9>`

Still works great!

Comment: But this fancy-pants mechanical keyboard I bought has no numpad! :(

Comment: @tony19 That's because it's an alt code. It's windows specific.

Comment: For Linux Ctrl-Shift-u 0-0-9-space-<ENTER>

Comment: @Chris you can just enter the numbers any way your keyboard supports -- it doesn't have to be entered on the numpad. :-)

Comment: @MrMas As far as I can recall, a number pad was always required for this. Indeed, the "number strip" on SteelSeries Apex Pro does not work for this. YMMV

Comment: @Chris must be a Windows thing -- on Linux I can enter the numbers for unicode however I want. :-)

Answer (score 2):

When working on Makefiles, I use Find/Replace using regexes.

Replace `^`     (4 spaces - change as appropriate) with `\t`.

Answer (score 1):

Strange, Visual Studio Code gives you a clue, but you have to hunt for it.

Turn off **"Editor: Detect Indentation"** which is **ON** by default.

After which, it will not assume that a tab is 4 spaces.

Of course, all you have to do is select your spaces, and then you will see "ghost dots" in your selection.  If you delete those spaces and then type tab, you will now see 1 "ghost right arrow" when you select it which means now you really have a tab character.

Answer (score -2):

You can turn off [editor.insertSpaces](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_indentation).

Comment: I think this actually works when combined with the answer from @World Python Developer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/72766544/1666926)